# Fit gamma distribution parameters to expectation and probabilty

Tags: python, sympy, gamma-distribution, gamma-function

My problem is the following. I measured a bunch of different physical properties and propagated the methodic and measurement uncertainties all the way to some kind of efficiency ratio. For all my physical properties, a normal distribution seemed to be a good choice, and for the first few calculations and corresponding propagations I had fairly low uncertainties. I forwarded all uncertainties as an extended uncertainty of kp=2 meaning coverage of 95.45% of all possible values.

However, for the calculations I am performing right now in order to get the efficiency I end up with results like (16+/-31)%, which is not possible since my efficiency can only spread from 0 to 1. My assumption would be, that I found the "correct" expectation value for the efficiency, but my probability distribution should be a positive skewed gamma-distribution rather than a normal-distribution. With the assumption that the intervals [0; 0.16+0.31], [0; 0.16+0.31*3/2] and [0;1] cover 95.45%, 99.73% and 100% of all possible values I should be able to calculate the gamma-distribution parameters alpha and beta analytically. Unfortunately, the following code using sympy doesn't work because sympy can't handle it.

Does someone have an idea how to solve my problem?

```
import sympy as sy
# from sympy import init_printing
# from sympy import symbols
# from sympy import Eq
# from sympy import var
# from sympy import integrate
# from sympy import gamma
# from sympy import Pow
# from sympy import exp

R_std3 = float(31 * 3/2 * 1/100)
R = float(16 * 1/100)
R_plus = R + R_std3

alpha = sy.symbols('alpha', positive = True)
beta = sy.symbols('beta', positive = True)
r = sy.symbols('r', positive = True)

z = sy.Pow(beta, alpha) * sy.Pow(r, alpha-1) * sy.exp(-beta*r)
n = sy.gamma(alpha)
pdf = sy.Pow(n, -1) * z

system = [sy.Eq(R, sy.Pow(beta, -1) * alpha ), 
          sy.Eq(0.9973, sy.integrate(pdf, (r,0,R_plus) ))
          ]

sy.solve( system )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect the second (transcendental) equation to have a nice analytic solution unless there's some clever identity that you can use to simplify it. You can solve this numerically though:

```
In [46]: system
Out[46]: 
⎡       α           α⋅γ(α, 0.625⋅β)⎤
⎢0.16 = ─, 0.9973 = ───────────────⎥
⎣       β               Γ(α + 1)   ⎦

In [47]: nsolve(system, [alpha, beta], [1, 10])
Out[47]: 
⎡2.16365408317279⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎣ 13.52283801983 ⎦
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solved the programming problem. However, you are right that this is not a satisfying answer from a mathematical point of view.